# Were there several layers of Titans in each wall, or how is it possible they could cover the whole Earth?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In this map, [World of Attack on Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan#/media/File:World_of_AoT.png) , they show Paradis Island and the rest of the world. The walls are rings inside the Island, if there is a single layer of Titans, the width they could cover is the size of the walls. When they walk away of the island, they would separate and couldnt cover the whole Earth.

[image]

The only possibility is there are several layers of Titans in each wall, but I dont think that's what we saw or what the series meant, is it?

Were there several layers of Titans in each wall, or how is it possible they could cover the whole Earth?

Comment: Interesting notion. I've always thought that during the Rumbling the Titans would form a line and then proceed all in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct answer here but a couple of points to consider

1. There are three walls, not one. And those three walls contain **millions** of colossal titans. At least according to Willie Tybur in chapter 100 of the Manga

   > Wall Sheena. Wall Rose. Wall Maria. His three walls, named after the three daughters of Ymir, the Founder ...are made of what must be millions of Colossus Titans.
2. The Titans don't need to keep a tight ring. The goal is for them to march over the surface of the planet, exterminating any humans. With 70% of the world covered by water, that's not as big a feat as you might think. The Titans need only sweep themselves over the land masses. They need not maintain themselves in a circle to do this.